# PrimeFaces Gmap not rendering (in the simplest example)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have one of the simplest possible pages with a `p:gmap` on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            Map:
            <p:gmap center="49.967109, 8.80198" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" />
        </h:body>
    </f:view>

</html>
```

However, this shows absolutely nothing under the Map: heading.

I realize that the script connects to some places, but nothing is rendered.

**Q:** What's wrong and how do you fix this?

PS: I'm using all versions of PF 3.x ... exchanging them didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the height and width :

```
<p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:600px;height:400px" />
```

Comment: I've never seen any component **require** some kind of CSS... strange. Thank you.

Comment: ..but you can find this information in the primefaces-userguide: `Four options are required to place a gmap on a page, these are
center, zoom, type and style` (p.193)

Comment: Yeah, but when you look at the showcase it nowhere states the JavaScript that needs to be put into h:head. Until I found out I had already removed the style attribute, too. Bad luck.